# Problem With DNS or Wordpress installation>

Tags: hosting, dns

So I added an addon domain in cpanel. Before I had registered this domain through a hosting company, so I just changed the DNS at their site pointing to my new location(siteground). Also I used the DNS adresses from my primary domain at siteground. When I try to access the site - "dns cannot be resolved".

Could there be some sort of issues with the DNS settings being wrong? Or maybe there is something wrong with wordpress installation/ databases etc?

Is there a good way to find the root of the problem?

Comment: This doesn't sound like an error message from WP core. Likely question better aimed at hosting support.

Answer (score 0):

This is a hosting question, as mentioned above. However, if you are going to host your DNS for the addon domain on Siteground, then you need to specify the nameservers for Siteground on your registrar. If your DNS will be hosted somewhere other than Siteground, then you will specify the IP address of the installation on Siteground.